# PhantomJS Not Rendering PDFs/PNGs with Highcharts correctly

Tags: pdf, highcharts, phantomjs

I want to be able to export to PDF the whole webpage with highcharts on it. The issue is that PDFs (or PNG) created through PhantomJS are not rendered correctly. I have bar charts and the width of these bars on PDF is nothing like what the actual chart is. The text on the page and layout is perfect. I have gone through a lot of recommended solutions but nothing has worked. Tried to set the EnableMouseTracker to false and Tooltip to false as well, that hasn't work either. Can someone recommend something please.

This seems to be an issue with bar charts in particular as the line chart looks correct when I set animation to false. Here are the fiddle(s) -

[Fiddle for chart that renders well](http://jsfiddle.net/jvisser/aKJLv/)

[One that doesn't](http://jsfiddle.net/x7rhmfrk/)

I am using below setting on chart that doesn't render well.

```
plotOptions: {
                    bar: {
                        animation: false,

                    }
```

Below is screenshot for the page with both the charts.

[image]

Is there other alternative to what I am trying to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: You also need to add a minimal but reproducible code to the question itself.

Comment: Please ensure if you have the newest highcharts and highcharts-convert.js form our remo. Please attach your chart configuarion, because on my phantomJS it works properly. Conf: {
    "chart": {
     "type":"bar",
        "renderTo": "container"
    },
    "series": [{
        "data": [ 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11]
    }]
}